# Adding overlay plot with vertical lines causes error in plotly R

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I have a plot that I would like to add vertical lines to separate out regions in the data. I have colored the original data with colors based on the data values. But when I add the code to apply the lines I get the following error:

Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:

- Length 2: Columns `x`, `y`
- Length 100: Columns `name`, `color`

I have recreated my situation with the sample code provided here using the Nile data. Why is this happening and what could I do to rectify the problem?

```
library(plotly)

data("Nile")
n = Nile
df <- data.frame(n)
df$size <- ifelse(n> 999, 'Large', 'Small') 

rmean20 = stats::filter(df$n, rep(1/20, 20), side=2)

colorSet <- c("red","green")

p.rm = plot_ly(df, x=x, y=n, type="scatter", mode="markers", name=df$size, color = ~size, colors = colorSet)
p.rm = add_lines(p.rm, x=x, y=rmean20, name="Bandwidth = 20")
p.rm = layout(p.rm, title = "Running mean")
print(p.rm)

p.rm = add_lines(p.rm, x = c(40, 40), y = c(400, 1400))
print(p.rm)
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately your example isn't reproducible: `object 'x' not found`

Comment: That's part of the problem.  If you run the example up to the first print you get a nice plot of what I'm looking for.  Now I want to add the vertical line via the next statement. When you execute the final print you get the error I mentioned.

Comment: If you remove the 'name=df$size, color=~size, colors=colorSet' from the plot_ly line the code works, but then I can't name (and color) the markers.

Comment: I did find another way to accomplish what I want - the use of add_segments instead of trying to add_lines.

Comment: In your example `x` isn't defined at all, removing `name=df$size, color = ~size, colors = colorSet` doesn't help here. But good you've found a solution.